# Another exception was thrown: Null check operator used on a null value!!1

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I tried to change the password in app with flutter (Firebase) but it give me and error Another exception was thrown: Null check operator used on a null value. so can someone help me fix this one.
do I need to add something to check null or remove something.

```
 class ChangingPasswordScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/ChangingPasswordScreen';
  //late final String? email;
  //final User user;

  //ChangingPasswordScreen({required this.user});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _ChangingPasswordState();
  }
}

class _ChangingPasswordState extends State<ChangingPasswordScreen> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  var newPassword = " ";

  final newPasswordController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    newPasswordController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  final currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

  changePassword() async {
    try {
      await currentUser!.updatePassword(newPassword);
      FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => SigninScreen(),
        ),
      );
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Text('Your Password has been changed'),
        ),
      );
    } catch (error) {}
  }



ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                    setState(() {
                      newPassword = newPasswordController.text;
                    });
                    changePassword();
                  }
                },
                child: Text(
                  'Change Password',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
                ),
              ),
```

Answer (score 0):

In,

```dart
await currentUser!.updatePassword(newPassword);
```

make sure that `currentUser` is not null before using `!`. `!` indicate that the variable will never be null.

Try something like this,

```dart
if(currentUser != null){
  try {
      await currentUser!.updatePassword(newPassword);
      FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => SigninScreen(),
        ),
      );
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Text('Your Password has been changed'),
        ),
      );
    } catch (error) {
      print("Error thrown : $error");
    }
}
```

Note: Never leave a `catch` block empty. Log the error while debugging. Handle the error properly. If you leave a `catch` block empty, you'll never know if it throws an Exception or not.

Comment: can I have your email so we can discuss more in this problem. I really need this fix. Thank you so much